# How do I have JavaScript get a substring before a character?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a paragraph that says 55+5. I want to have JavaScript return everything before the plus. Is this possible using substrings?

Comment: Do you mean substring?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. Try the `String.split` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

`split()` returns an array of strings, split by the character you pass to it (in your case, the plus). Just use the first element of the array; it will have everything before the plus:

```js
const string = "foo-bar-baz"
const splittedString = string.split('-')
//splittedString is a 3 element array with the elements 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz'
```

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, the site is full of errors. Use [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) or ECMA-262.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that before. Changed to MDN.

Answer (score 35):

Do you mean substring instead of subscript? If so. Then yes.

```
var string = "55+5"; // Just a variable for your input.

function getBeforePlus(str){

    return str.substring(0, str.indexOf("+")); 
   /* This gets a substring from the beginning of the string 
      to the first index of the character "+".
   */

}
```

Otherwise, I recommend using the [String.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method.

You can use that like so.

```
var string = "55+5"; // Just a variable for your input.

function getBeforePlus(str){

    return str.split("+")[0]; 
    /* This splits the string into an array using the "+" 
       character as a delimiter.
       Then it gets the first element of the split string.
    */

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

```
var str = '55+5';

var beforePlus = str.split('+').shift();

console.log(beforePlus);
// -> "55"
```